# Accessing Microsoft Graph with AAD App

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I begin with my question. How do I read data from my AAD using Microsoft Graph using an app registration perfomed inside of an Azure AD? Now the details...

I have created an app registration in my Azure Active Directory and allowed access to Microsoft Graph there:

[image: AAD portal with required permissions]

To be exact the app has the following permissions:

- Application Permissions

  - Read all users' relevant people lists and search the directory
  - Read all users' full profiles
- Delegated Permissions
  (None)

I use the following code in my ASP.NET MVC app to authenticate my website against the AAD:

```
public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = "/"
            },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

which is pretty much the default setting for doing organizational auth. This works and I even can read out my users informations from the AAD profile:

```
private string GetUserName()
{                        
    var claimsPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;           
    var firstName = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value;
    var lastName = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;
    return $"{firstName} {lastName}";
}
```

Now I try to use Microsoft Graph to optain lets say the avatar image. There are some official MS samples available [here](https://github.com/search?q=aspnet%20sample%20user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories). But all of them rely on a NuGet package called `Microsoft.Identity.Client` which is preview currently. The other thing is that MS wants me to register my app under [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) which makes no sense to me because I already have an registered app.

I already tries to retrieve my bearer token from my claims identity and use it in Graph like this:

```
var ci = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;
var token = ((System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext)ci.BootstrapContext).Token;
var endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpoint))
    {                    
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);                 
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }                    
    }
}
return null;
```

But this gives my 401.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a token with ADAL using your app's client id and secret.

You can get ADAL from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

E.g.:

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-id";
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

string clientId = "your-app-client-id";
string clientSecret = "yourappclientsecret";
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);

string accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

Replace *your-tenant-id* with your Azure AD tenant id or domain name (e.g. mytenant.onmicrosoft.com). Replace *your-app-client-id* with the client id/application id of the app registered in AAD. Replace *yourappclientsecret* with the client secret/key created for the app in AAD.

I have hard-coded them in the example to make it easier to follow. In production you should not be storing credentials in code.